# split string in java through keword

Tags: java, string, split

I am writing a code, in which i want to split the following string:

```
String str = "{route=Head west on, some address, distance=0.2 km, duration=1 min}";
```

I want to separate the value for route, distance and duration.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: it was fairly easy if they was no comma(,) in this line `Head west on, some address`

Comment: Yes but i am getting the result in such a format only.

Comment: @Himanshu you should post what you have tried.. before your question gets closed

Comment: @sanbhat: I also thought of splitting the string with (,) but in few cases i am getting the (,) within the value itself as mentioned. Now i am stuck because i don't know how should i approach to split that sort of format.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
   String str = "{route=Head west on, some address, distance=0.2 km, duration=1 min}";
    String newStr=str.replaceAll("\\}","");
    String[] arr=newStr.split("route=");
    String[] arr1=arr[1].split("distance=");
    String route=arr1[0];
    String[] arr2=arr1[1].split("duration=");
    String  distance=arr2[0];
    String duration=arr2[1];

    System.out.println("route= "+route);
    System.out.println("distance= "+distance);
    System.out.println("duration= "+duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expression for splitting a string:

```
String str = "{route=Head west on, some address, distance=0.2 km, duration=1 min}";
String regEx = "(\\{route=|distance=|duration=|\\})";
// String regEx = "(route=|distance=|duration=)";
String[] splited = str.split(regEx);
for(String s: splited) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

You can add any other keyword (just add it to regEx) without changing code!

Answer (score 0):

Try out using the `StringTokenizer` to split the string as below:

> ```
> final String SPLIT_STR = ",";
>   String str = "{route=Head west on, some address, distance=0.2 km, duration=1 min}"; 
>   final StringTokenizer stToken = new StringTokenizer(
>      str, SPLIT_STR);
>   final String[] splitStr = new String[stToken.countTokens()];
>   int index = 0;
>   while(stToken.hasMoreElements()) {
>      splitStr[index++] = stToken.nextToken();
>   }
>   for(index=0; index < splitStr.length; index++) {
>      System.out.println("Tokenizer : " + splitStr[index]);
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Hope this will work for you.